# unable to decode the encoded keystore.jks file in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application.yml file with value as

```
  ssl:
    keys:
      store: abc
      password: cGFkc3Bhc3N3b3Jk
      algorithm: JKS
      alias: chjkcw==
      key-password: cGFkc6Khc3N3b3Jk
```

where abc is the encoded value of my keystore.jks file

Now I am trying to retrieve the privateKey from that file using

```
        this.password = decodeBase64(password);
        String decodedAlias = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(alias), UTF_8);
        keyStore = loadKeyStore(Base64.getDecoder().decode(store), this.password, algorithm);
        privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(decodedAlias, decodeBase64(keyPassword));

        private static KeyStore loadKeyStore(byte[] keyStoreBytes, char[] password, String algorithm)
            throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(algorithm);
        keyStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(keyStoreBytes), password);
        return keyStore;
    }
```

This code is giving me `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/abc]`

When I gave these details to my colleague who is using eclipse ide, it works for him and I am using intellij. Not sure if this is ide issue. Also, is there any dependency missing? Which dependency do I need?

Comment: Please share the full exception with stacktrace.

Comment: What is the exact location difference between folder ABC and the / top folder of your webapp, second, the Keystone folder is usually configured to the SSL TLS in the server configuration.

Comment: abc is not a folder. It is the encoded string of keystore.jks file